# Is there a limit on how many times Google Chrome can reload the contents of applicationCache?

Tags: html, google-chrome, application-cache

Is there a limit on how many times Google Chrome can reload the contents of applicationCache? I've noticed (and I'll be the first to admit that it's a little vague) that there seems to be a hard limit on how many times I can reload my web app before Chrome seems to stop replacing the files in application cache.

Chrome will still go through the motions of downloading the files listed in the manifest (I can see it happen in the console), it definitely can access the newer versions of the files, it just doesn't update the application cache files. I have to go into the browser preferences and nuke the application cache there. The application cache is about 2.4M. It may just be a random corruption issue, but I thought it worthwhile to ask here.

I'm using a build process whereby the manifest is updated with a random string to force a complete reload every time I do a build, which is often enough. I hadn't set about counting the number of reloads, it hasn't happened that often, but I've seen it before. I've also updated Chrome in that time period, so it isn't a specific version of Chrome or OS (recent releases, Mac OS 10.8.x to 10.9.x). If I see it again then I may try an automated test setup to try and prove it programmatically.

Comment: You could go to `chrome://appcache-internals/` to see if you can spot any problems there the next time you encounter it. Also note that it retrieves the manifest twice, once at start and once at end of the update process, so if it changes during the update process, the update isn't applied (which does seem to match your symptoms).

Comment: D'oh. After all this time, I did not know that this was there. I realise that it doesn't count as an actual answer, but thank you, that would be a great place to start.